# Spark MLlib: Run Algorithm on non-RDD Input Dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to run [Spark's Linear Regression algorithm](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD) with an input that is not an RDD (i.e. a `Vector` or `List`). Unfortunately, it looks like the [run interface](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD@run(input:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint],initialWeights:org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector):M) for that and [its parent class](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm) accepts only `RDD[LabeledPoint]` and no other collection of `LabeledPoints`s. Is there any way to use the linear regression algorithm without an RDD as input?

I am running into this issue because I have an RDD of datasets. Each dataset needs to use the linear regression algorithm. The individual datasets are not huge, so they are fine to store in memory as `List`s or `Vector`s. The *number* of datasets, however, is huge, which is why that needs to be stored in an RDD. Is there any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I know [Spark doesn't support RDDs of RDDs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063) and creating a new Spark Context inside of the `RDD.map(...)` function seems a bit ridiculous, but I can't think of another way to use MLlib's algorithms on an RDD of datasets.

Comment: Why even bother with expensive approximation if data is small enough to be handled with a local data structure?

Comment: Are you suggesting MLlib's linear regression algorithm is unnecessarily expensive to compute a linear regression model on a small dataset?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my point.

Comment: My thinking behind it is that I already have the MLlib dependency, so I'd rather use that instead of bringing in another dependency. I haven't done any benchmarking, but unless MLlib is slower than simpler algorithms (because it uses RDDs which is overkill) I don't see why I shouldn't use MLlib in this situation.